# Array vs Dictionary - fight! What's the fastest way to search through a large dataset?

Tags: arrays, performance, dictionary, swift, mapkit

Calling all computer scientists - I need your expert advice :)

Here's my problem:

- I have a mapping application, and I've divided the world into 10 million possible squares of fixed size(latitude/longitude, ie double/double data type).  Let's call that data set D1.
- A second set of data, call it D2, is around 20,000 squares of the same size (latitude/longitude, or double/double data type), and represents locations of interest in my app.
- When the user zooms in far enough, I want to display all the squares of interest that are in the present view, but not the ones outside the view, because that's way too many for the app to handle (generating overlays, etc.) without getting completely bogged down.

So rather than submitting 20,000 overlay squares for rendering and letting the Mapkit framework manage what gets shown (it completely chokes on that much data), here are a few things I've tried to optimize performance:

1) Put D2 in an array.  Iterate through every possible visible square on my view, and for each possible square do a lookup in D2 (using Swift's find() function) to see if the corresponding element exists in that array.  If it exists, display it.  This is really slow -> if my view has an area of 4000 squares viewable, I have to check 4000 squares * 20000 points in the array = up to 80 million lookups = SLOW..

2) Put D2 in an array.  Iterate through D2 and for each element in D2, check if that element is within the bounds of my view.  If it is, display it.  This is better than #1 (only takes 10% of the time of #1) but still on the slow side

3) Put D2 in an array.  Iterate through D2 and create a new array D3 which filters out (using Swift's array.filter() method with a closure) all datapoints outside the view, then submit just those points for rendering.  This is fastest (about 2% of original time of #1) but still too slow (depending on the data pattern, can still take several seconds of processing on an iphone4).

I have been thinking about dictionaries or other data structures.  Would I expect a dictionary populated with key=(latitude,longitude) and value = (true/false) to be faster to look up than an array?  I'm thinking if a map view with bounds y2, y1, x2, x1, I could do a simple for{} loop to find all the dictionary entries in those bounds with value = true (or even no value; all I'd really need is something like dictionarydata.exists(x,y), unless a value is absolutely required to build a dictionary).  This would be much faster, but again it depends on how fast a dictionary is compared to an array.

Long story short: is searching through a large dictionary for a key a lot faster than searching through an array?  I contemplated sorting my array and building a binary search as a test, but figured dictionaries might be more efficient.  Since my array D2 will be built dynamically over time, I'd rather commit much more time/resources per addition (which are singular in nature) in order to absolutely maximize lookup performance later (which are orders of magnitude more data to sift through).

Appreciate any/all advice - are dictionaries the way to go?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: This could very easily be an XY problem, if for example `mapkit` implements something which already does this (i.e. see [google maps api's solution to same issue](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#viewportmarkermanagement). Consider adding at least `swift` and `mapkit` tags (you would have to remove 2 current tags). Also consider shortening question and adding a more specific title. It seems like a relatively simple problem, which may or may not require a complex solution, but regardless it should not take this long to describe.

Comment: As far as the general question. I would guess optimal would be using either a two-dimensional data structure which is doubly sorted by longitude and latitude, or just two ds's. Not sure which particular ds would be optimal though.

Comment: I agree with @BroSlow, a 2D data structure would probably be best. Then you can just compute between which indices your data lies, and pass that. If you want to optimize for cache, you can also try blocking your data, but I doubt if it'll bring much gain, unless there is reuse of the data.

Comment: Oh, and this reference may help you decide: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity It only states Complexity, but it's still important to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing off of the examples in the comments here. Create a two dimensional array sorted on both the X and Y axes. Then do a binary search to find the NW corner and the SE corner elements. Then all the elements in the box formed by those two corners need to be displayed.